References on Kolmogorov-Sinai (measure-theoretic) entropy and convergence of measures
I want to learn what happens to Kolmogorov-Sinai entropy (a.k.a. measure-theoretic entropy) when I take the limit in some sense:

Let's say $(X,\mathfrak B)$ - measurable space and $T:X\rightarrow X$ - measure-preserving (and may be invertible) transformation. Let's also consider probability measures $\mu_n$ that converge to probability measure $\mu$ in some sense (for example, if $X$ equipped with topology we can consider weak convergence). What can we say about $h(\mu_n, T)$ and $h(\mu,T)$? Is it true that $h(\mu_n, T)\longrightarrow h(\mu,T)$?
I wonder if there are concepts of ''convergence of measure-preserving systems'':
$$(X_n, \mathfrak B_n, \mu_n, T_n)\longrightarrow(X,\mathfrak B,\mu,T)$$
and if there are some results about entropy behaviour under such limits.

So I'm looking for books/papers/reviews which could help me with such questions. Can you give me some recommendations?
Thank you

This is nowhere close to a full answer, but a place you can read about this is in Peter Walters book, "An introduction to ergodic theory". Specifically, he discusses in chapter 8.1 properties of the entropy map, given a continuous $T:X\to X$ over a  compact metric space.
He says there that the map assigning an entropy value to an invariant measure is not even upper semi-continuous, while giving a counterexample right before theorem 8.2. He also gives cases where the entropy map is upper semi continuous, which would mean in those cases that $\lim_{n\to \infty} h(\mu_n,T) \leq h(\mu,T)$ when $\mu_n\to \mu$ weakly. This already suggests that you usually won't have continuity results for the entropy.

Thank you! Great book

In his paper "INVERSE LIMITS, ENTROPY AND WEAK ISOMORPHISM
FOR DISCRETE DYNAMICAL SYSTEM" James R. Brown shows that entropy respects inverse limit of measure-preserving systems.
